# I need a full height container with special footer and content behavior

Tags: css

Here I prepared a jsfiddle to show the situation I am in: You see a simple header, content, footer structure.

Inside the content-container is a messenger that should stretch to MAX 100% height. Above 100% height it should scroll - that's it.

EDITED: 100% content-height means: The content-container stretches between header and footer. So header and footer are always visible. The Content-container stretches between them and the messenger inside the content-container too, but messenger starts to scroll, when its content (the messages) grows.

But: The footer has got a 'special' behavior: It is sticky as long as it doesn't reach the content inside the content-container and always stays at the bottom as long as the content is less than 100% height.

Sorry - I couldn't post a link to my fiddle because stackoverflow is extremely buggy here with its stupid "jusfiddle links must be accomplished by code"

```css
/*BASIC STRUCTURE*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%; /*not working without set position absolute*/
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: #2980b9;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 70px; /*Height must be flexible*/
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.content-container {
  background: #336E7B;
  max-width: 1010px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px 10px 40px 10px;
}

.footer {
  background: #2980b9;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
}


/*END BASIC STRUCTURE*/


/*MESSENGER STRUCTURE*/

.messenger-container {
  display: flex;
}

.my-contacts {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-width: 275px;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:100%; /*not working yet */
}

.message-window {
  background: #333;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height:100%; /*not working yet*/
}

.single-message {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.input-field-dummy{
  background: #F00;
}
https://jsfiddle.net/25vrsr2m/
/*END MESSENGER STRUCTURE*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> <!--maybe remove the wrapper?-->
  <div class="header">HEADER - flexible height</div>
  <div class="content-container">
  MESSAGE CONTAINER
    <div class="messenger-container">    
      <div class="my-contacts">
        <p>CONTACT 1</p>
        <p>CONTACT 2</p>
        <p>CONTACT 3</p>
        <p>CONTACT 4</p>
        <p>CONTACT 5</p>
        <p>CONTACT 6</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message-window">
        <div class="single-message">Single message</div>
        <div class="single-message">Remove me and resize window from large to small multiple times to see footer behavior</div>
        <div class="single-message">Remove me and resize window from large to small multiple times to see footer behavior</div>
        <p class="input-field-dummy">
  INPUT FIELD GOES HERE - always sticky at the bottom of message window.
  </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER - always at the bottom, sticky until it reaches content of content-container, then it stays below</div>
</div>

<!--
Here goes my js and css before body ends
-->
```

Comment: Please explain the problem instead of simply downvoting the question -.-

Comment: Do you want the right div, same hight as left div and beyned that scrollable, while footer is at the bottom but not overlapping the content?

Comment: Hmm yes it should be the same hight but more important is, that both divs are always 100% height, but scrollable if content is too large for 100% height. Exactly! Footer always at bottom, but not overlapping the content. Its the same behavior as whatsapp web messenger or xing messenger.

Comment: What do you mean by 100% hight? to cover all the page except for the header and footer?

Comment: EDITED: 100% content-height means: When the content-container stretches between header and footer. So header and footer are always visible. content container stretches between them and the messenger too, but messenger starts to scroll, when its content grows.

Comment: Check if this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vjj1589/2/) is helpful for you, I've added `position: sticky` to .header and .footer, and `overflow-y: scroll & max-height:300px` to .message-window

Comment: Thanks for your first solution but that is the problem: The footer is not at the bottom anymore and the messenger is sometimes bigger than 300px :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160340/discussion-between-cowcrazy-and-user-name).

Answer (score 0):

try:
height: calc(100% -heightoffooter+header)
and overflow scroll ofc

when your header is dynamic as you said you might use JS for it

Comment: Hmm no I try to find a solution without js. I also tried to set the display of the wrapper to flex and flex-direction: column, but then the footer overlaps the content...

Comment: well when having dynamic headerheight it wont work without js. but as said you can calc the height with 100vh and minus the combined header+footerheight and then you should have the height you want to have